# Invoking function defined inside an Angularjs Controller using Selenium webdriver

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angularjs-scope, webdriver

We are currently using selenium for out Automation. 
I have a angular js code defined as below.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
myController.$inject = ['$scope', '$cookies', '$http', '$timeout', '$window'];

function myController($scope, $cookies, $http, $timeout, $window) {
   var vm = this;
   vm.handleResponse = handleResponse;
    //More code 
    ....
   function handleResponse(Response) {
    .......
  }
}
```

I want to Invoke the handleResponse function from my selenium script. 
I have used JavascriptExecutor as below for non AngularJS code. But this doesn't seem to work with angular

```
JavascriptExecutor jse =  (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("var response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(" + sign + "));" +
        "window.handleResponse(response);");
```

How can this be done with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to execute a function of your app? when testing with selenium, usually tests are written as a "black box", you don't know what client framework you are running.

If you really want to do that, you can check what protractor does when you call [`addMockModule`](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.addMockModule), the basic idea is:

1. Mark to angular not to auto bootstrap, (even if you are used `ng-app` directive).
2. Add mock module as a dependency of your app module.
3. Manual bootstrap the app module.

Check out that [code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.4.0/lib/browser.ts#L954).

The other approach would load angular with debug info, (can be done with invoking `angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()`). Then grab you root element and get a reference of your app `injector`.

```
const injector = angular.element(document.getElementById('root')).injector()
const $controller = injector.get('$controller');
const ctrlName = $controller('ctrlName', locals = {});
ctrlName.youFunc();
```

Referances:

1. [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)
2. [$controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$controller)

Comment: I need to invoke that function explicitly with some custom variables in my End to end test. I see you have linked some protractor resources. Is there a way to do it with Selenium in Java? In the case of plain js, I could do it by using window.functionName() and the function was in global scope. How can I do the same when the function is defined inside the controller ?